# How to insert conditional text in a p tag on a cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I Have this portion of cshtml page part of my Razor application:

```
<p style="text-align: justify">
    thank you for confirming your reservation for the <b>@{ @Model.HotelChoiceDescription.Substring(@Model.HotelChoiceDescription.IndexOf("_") + 1) }</b>
</p>


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription))
            {
<!-- Verify if english -->
            if (Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTENG#") && Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#ENDENG#"))
            {
<p style="text-align: justify">
    @(new HtmlString(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Substring(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#STARTENG#") + 10, Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#ENDENG#") - Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#STARTENG#") - 10))) for the period @Model.ReservationDate
</p>
            }

<!-- default -->
            if (!Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTENG#") && !Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTITA#"))
            {
<p style="text-align: justify">
    @(new HtmlString(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription)) for the period @Model.ReservationDate
</p>
            }
            }
```

The result is:

```
thank you for confirming your reservation for the Giant Hotel

Single room (eur. 44,00/night) for the period August 20, 2022 - August 27, 2022.
```

But to reduce the spaces and consequently the pages to be printed, the best result would be this:

```
thank you for confirming your reservation for the Giant Hotel Single room (eur. 44,00/night) for the period August 20, 2022 - August 27, 2022.
```

All the text in the same paragraph

I tried to put everything inside the first tag p but it also prints the if and the "{"
I also tried entering @if, but it doesn't load the page because it goes in error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to only use a `<p></p>`:

```
<p style="text-align: justify">
    thank you for confirming your reservation for the <b>@{ @Model.HotelChoiceDescription.Substring(@Model.HotelChoiceDescription.IndexOf("_") + 1) }</b>



    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription))
    {
        <!-- Verify if english -->
        if (Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTENG#") && Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#ENDENG#"))
        {

            @(new HtmlString(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Substring(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#STARTENG#") + 10, Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#ENDENG#") - Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.IndexOf("#STARTENG#") - 10)+" for the period "+Model.ReservationDate))
        }

        <!-- default -->
        if (!Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTENG#") && !Model.TypeOfRoomDescription.Contains("#STARTITA#"))
        {
            @(new HtmlString(Model.TypeOfRoomDescription+" for the period "+Model.ReservationDate))
         }
    }
</p>
```

then the result will be in a line:

```
thank you for confirming your reservation for the Giant Hotel Single room (eur. 44,00/night) for the period August 20, 2022 - August 27, 2022.
```